# Error: spawn ENOTDIR, when selecting python interpreter in VS Code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, vscode-python

I have created django project and virtualenv into same folder as

[image]

opening-up vscode does not display the virtual environment in which the django project is using.

[image]

now if I select interpreter for the project I get

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in the version of the python extension I was using(2020.1.57204). what I did was installed a slightly older version (2019.11.50794) of the python extension and reload vscode i.e.,

Step 1: Click on Install Another Version

[image]

Step 2: Select the older version, here 2019.11.50794

[image]

Step 3: Click on Reload Required Button

[image]

## UPDATE

The Microsoft team fixed this error with the new release (2020.1.58038). Update the python extension to the new version to enjoy more enhancements and fixes.

Comment: Thank you! This saved me a ton of googling!

Comment: @r-puri You are welcome. Glad I could help. The Microsoft team fixed this error with the new release (2020.1.58038). Update the python extension to the new version to enjoy more enhancements and fixes.